# Sql query exception in symfony2 - left outer join

Tags: sql, join, symfony

I'm trying to get list of images in gallery, sum of ratings and number of voters. I do sql query:

```
    SELECT img.id, img.title, img.image, img.thumb, img.link, img.published, 
        rating.sum, rating.voters
    FROM AcmeMainBundle:Category cat, AcmeMainBundle:User usr, AcmeMainBundle:Image img                
    LEFT OUTER JOIN                        
    (
      SELECT SUM(r.rating) as sum, COUNT(r.rating) as voters, r.image
      FROM AcmeMainBundle:ImgRating r
    ) AS rating ON rating.image = img.id
    WHERE usr.username = :user AND cat.user = usr.id AND 
       cat.id = :category AND img.category = cat.id
    ORDER BY img.order ASC, img.id DESC
```

but i receive exception:

```
    [Semantical Error] line 0, col 253 near 'SELECT SUM(r.rating)': Error:         
    Identification Variable ( used in join path expression but was not defined before.
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I believe that's due subquerys not being supported in FROM/JOIN.

If I were you, I would try making a view with that subselect called "rating". If that doesn't work, you should re-structure your query in a different way =).

If you can't do it comment and I'll help.